# Android splash screen for tablet

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm developing a React Native application and now I'd like to add tablet support. I am facing a problem with the splash screen. It stretches to fit the screen size and it doesn't look so pretty. To add a splash screen I added the following line to my application style

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
```

and placed the image `splash.png` inside different folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc.) of different sizes.

What's the right way to add splash screens for tablets? What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: show your layout complete file.

Comment: what file are talking about?

Comment: your xml layout file for you activity?

Comment: there is no layout files because I'm using React Native. It creates activity from Java code